# How to distinguish two variables in rest

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Ok so maybe I am doing something wrong right at the beginning but I'm not sure and I'd like to understand a bit well how does work REST application.

Basically I'm using 2 urls which point to the **same controller** and the **same method**.

- `/blog/edit/{{id}}`
- `/blog/add/{{ajax}}`

### Controller

```
public function showEditIndex($id=null,$ajax=null) 
    {

        $article = new \stdClass();
        $article->id = "";
        $article->title = "";
        $article->content = "";
        $article->date = "";

        if($id != null){
            $tmp = DB::select('select * from blog where id = '.$id);
            $article->id = $tmp[0]->id;
            $article->title = $tmp[0]->title;
            $article->content = $tmp[0]->content;
            $article->date = $tmp[0]->date;
        }

        if($ajax=='ajax'){ //Ajoute ou Modifie

            $title = Input::get('title');
            $content = Input::get('content');
            $date = Input::get('date');
            if($date != null){
                $query = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('id', 1)
                    ->update(['title' => $title,'content' => $content, $date => date("F j, Y \a\t g:ia")]);
                return;
            }

            $query = DB::table('blog')->insertGetId(
                array('title' => $title, 'content' => $content)
            );

            return $query;
        }

        return view('blog.add')
        ->with('article',$article)
        ->withTitle('Edit Article');
    }
```

So it work well in the beginning but as long as I try to add or edit a variable I'm ending with this error.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ajax' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from blog where id = ajax)

Which make probably sense since he consider the first parameter `$id` to take {{ajax}} as value.

So how can I tell him to specifically distinguish the first, and seconde parameter of the controller?

Comment: I suggest you look into this crud tutorial for Laravel, you seem to be doing a lot of manual work where Laravel could simplify your code quite a lot. https://www.sitepoint.com/crud-create-read-update-delete-laravel-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going the wrong way.

When a Laravel route has only one placeholder (`/blog/edit/{id}` or `/blog/add/{ajax}`), the corresponding closure or controller method will always receive one parameter. So, contrary to your expectation, the `$ajax` parameter will never get passed to the method, neither in the case of `blog/edit` nor in the case of `blog/add`. It's the first parameter (`$id`) that gets filled in both cases. Have a look at the Laravel documentation on [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters).

What you need to do, is to either generalize the method logic to correctly work with only one parameter (`id` or whatever you name it) in both cases, or refactor the common logic into a new private method and have two separate route methods which make more sense.

At the end of the day, you'll ask yourself what's the reason to have two separate routes that do the exact same job?